# js variable comparison. Short version

Tags: javascript

i need to compare a variable with multiple values

```
let test = 'e'
if(test == 'q' || test == 'w' || test == 'e') console.log('TEST')
```

Can you make this entry shorter?

I present it this way, but it is not correct.

```
let test = 'e'
if(test == 'q' || 'w' || 'e') console.log('TEST')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array:

```js
const test = 'e'
if (['q', 'w', 'e'].includes(test)) {
  console.log('TEST');
}
```